# NodeJS Tic Tac Toe STDIN Confliction

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a game loop that runs this.turn() to continuously get user input. But when I run the code, the turn() functions all run at once and conflict with one another in STDIN.

The program does not stop and wait for input before going to the next iteration and function call.

How can I make it stop and wait for the input before moving to the next iteration?

```
const readline = require('readline');


function TicTacToe () {

  this.board = [];
  this.playerTurn = '';
  this.state = true;


  this.intitializeBoard = () => {
    for ( let i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
      this.board.push(i);
    }
  }


  this.printBoard = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i += 3 ) {
      console.log(this.board.slice(i, i + 3));
    }
  }


  this.determineFirstTurn = () => {
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if ( result == 0 ) {
      this.playerTurn = 'X';
    } else {
      this.playerTurn = 'O';
    }
  }


  this.prompt = () => {
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy\n', (input) => {
      if ( this.board[input] &&
            this.board[input] !== 'X' &&
            this.board[input] !== 'O' ) {

              this.board[input] = this.playerTurn;
              rl.close();
            } else {
              console.log("Incorrect input. Try again.");
              rl.close();
              this.prompt();
            }

    });
  }


  this.turn = () => {
    console.log("Player " + this.playerTurn + "'s Turn");

    this.printBoard();
    this.prompt();


    if ( this.playerTurn == 'X') {
      this.playerTurn = 'O';
    } else {
      this.playerTurn = 'X';
    }

  }


}



var game = new TicTacToe();

game.intitializeBoard();
game.determineFirstTurn();

game.board.forEach( () => {
  game.turn();
});
```

Terminal Output:

```
Player O's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player X's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player O's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player X's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player O's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player X's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player O's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player X's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
Player O's Turn
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 7, 8 ]
Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy
222222222222222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical for asynchronous code: you need to continue with dependent code when the callback is called.

This can also be solved with promises:

```
this.prompt = () => {
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    // Promisify the question method:
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        rl.question('Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy\n', resolve)
    })
    .then((input) => {
        if ( this.board[input] !== undefined &&
                this.board[input] !== 'X' &&
                this.board[input] !== 'O' ) {
            this.board[input] = this.playerTurn;
            rl.close(rl);
        } else {
            console.log("Incorrect input. Try again.");
            return this.prompt(); // Return a new promise
        }
    });
}
```

Then in the `turn` method, you need to treat the `this.prompt()` call as a promise as well, and return a promise to the caller:

```
this.turn = () => {
    console.log("Player " + this.playerTurn + "'s Turn");

    this.printBoard();
    return this.prompt().then( _ => {
        if ( this.playerTurn == 'X') {
            this.playerTurn = 'O';
        } else {
            this.playerTurn = 'X';
        }
    });
}
```

Finally in the main code, you need to treat the return value from `turn` as a promise, and chain promise after promise with `reduce` instead of `forEach`:

```
game.board.reduce( prom => prom.then(game.turn), Promise.resolve() )
    .then( _ => {
        console.log('Game over');
        game.printBoard();
    });
```

Note I corrected a problem in this line of code, which will not work well for when *input* is 0

```
if ( this.board[input] && ...
```

Instead do:

```
if ( this.board[input] !== undefined && ...
```

Comment: Because then `this.board[input]` is falsy and your `if` condition will not be `true`. By doing `!== undefined` you make it true also for when `this.board[input]` is 0.

Comment: I'm confused. I know you are right because I tested it, but doesn't this.board[0] == 0 ? I use console.log to check and it shows 0, but you are right that it does not work when the input is 0...and I don't understand xD

Comment: If something is 0, it is considered `false` when used just like that in a conditional expression. So if you put in your condition `this.board[input]` without any further comparison, the condition will return `false` when that value is 0 or `undefined` or `null`. That is not what you want to happen. You only want that test to be `false` when you had not yet assigned a value to `this.board[input]` (i.e. when it is `undefined`). So you need to explicitly mention that in your condition.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 2):

`readline.question` is not a blocking call, so program execution will continue.

One way to create sequential behaviour would be to make the `readline.question` callback invoke the next turn, i.e.

```
this.prompt = () => {
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.question('Enter the number of the square you wish to occupy\n', (input) => {
      if ( this.board[input] &&
            this.board[input] !== 'X' &&
            this.board[input] !== 'O' ) {

              this.board[input] = this.playerTurn;
              rl.close();
              this.turn(); // once we have validated input, move to the next turn
            } else {
              console.log("Incorrect input. Try again.");
              rl.close();
              this.prompt();
            }

    });
  }
```

Then just call turn once to start the game:

```
var game = new TicTacToe();

game.intitializeBoard();
game.determineFirstTurn();

game.turn();
```